# Take snapshot of not initialized view in Xamarin.Forms/Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I would like to add a cart icon with badge to the application toolbar provided by Xamarin Forms. I didnt find any way to add a badge to toolbaritem. My friend came up with an idea to create simple view of this icon and take a snapshot of this view.

I tried to create a platform specyfic service that will be responsible for creating a snapshot of provided Xamarin.Forms.View but it doesn't work becouse (as I assume) this view is not rendered.

XF Code:

```cs
var iconView = new CartIconView();
var imageSource = DependencyService.Get<IViewSnapshotRenderer>().GenereteSnapshotImageSource(iconView);
```

Xamarin Andoid Code:

```cs
public ImageSource GenereteSnapshotImageSource(View view)
        {
            if (Platform.GetRenderer(view) == null)
                Platform.SetRenderer(view, Platform.CreateRenderer(view));

            var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(view);
            var nativeView = renderer.View;
            nativeView.Invalidate();
            nativeView.RefreshDrawableState();

            var wasDrawingCacheEnabled = nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled;
            nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = true;
            nativeView.BuildDrawingCache(false);
            var bitmap = nativeView.DrawingCache;
            nativeView.DrawingCacheEnabled = wasDrawingCacheEnabled;

            var imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
            {
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, memoryStream);
                memoryStream.Seek(0L, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return memoryStream;

            });
            return imageSource;
        }
```

In this case bitmap is null

Is there any way to Force Xamarin.Andoid.View initialization despite the fact it will be not displayed? Or maybe do you know any better idea to create a snapshot of not displayed view? Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to take snapshot of the screen when app in the background?

Comment: No. I have created an "IconView" and I want to convert this to to image to use is as icon (I do not want to display this view anywhere, just take snapshot of this view). To give you more details it is View with cart icon as background and label that will imitate a badge. The result image would looks like: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1692829/cart_number_one_shopping_shopping_cart_icon

Answer (score 0):

You have too little control on ToolbarItem with the `NavigationBar` provided by `Xamarin.Forms`.

I will suggest you to disable the navigation bar (`NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)`), then to create your own toolbar. Which is really easy since it's basically a `Grid` with a `Label` and as many `Buttons` you want.

Doing that you can really easily create a custom `BadgeButton` with a `Grid` and a rounded Frame.

See this code for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Xamarin.CustomControls.BadgeButton">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="BadgeIconImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="6" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
            <Frame x:Name="BadgeFrame" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="12" Padding="10,4" HasShadow="false" OutlineColor="Transparent">
                <Label x:Name="BadgeTextLabel" FontSize="12" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

source: https://github.com/DottorPagliaccius/Xamarin-Custom-Controls/tree/master/src/Xamarin.CustomControls.BadgeButton

Comment: Which tabs? I would like to convert XF Forms view to image or add a badge to ToolbarItem (in navigation bar).

Comment: Yes and I'm telling you, don't use TabbedPage as they are not flexible. You need custom Tabs to do what you are doing, and this is what the lib provides :)

Comment: Thank you for your time, but I do not understand your approach. Could you give me more details?

To give you more details it is View with cart icon as background and label that will imitate a badge. The result image would looks like: https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/1692829/cart_number_one_shopping_shopping_cart_icon

I want to convert this to image so I could use it as ImageSource of an element of Navigation.ToolbarItems.

Comment: erf sorry. What a goof, don't know why I read tab item instead of toolbar item. I will update my answer :)